# Why my addeventlistener only working in one button?

Tags: javascript, php, database

Been stuck here all day long trying to debug what is wrong with my code. Why the eventlistener only work in One button? even though I am using class in querySelector.

I am using PHP to iterates ALL the data from my database hence also the button is being loop too.

PHP/HTML

```
<?php
    foreach ($employees  as $employee) {     

    ?>

    <td><?php echo $employee['name']?></td>
    <td>Php. <?php echo $employee['salary']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $employee['address']?></td>
    <td>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info showBtn" name="showBtn" 
    id="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">View 
    Employee</a>
    </td>

    <?php }?>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector('.showBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert("test");
    })
```

buttons to all `<td>` should alert but it only working in the first button. can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Probably because you're using the same "id" for the button. Hard to say without seeing more related code. Seeing this is database related, it suggests it.

Comment: I deleted the id="showBtn" but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)** which will return matching class list and then using **[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to loop through the `classes` and add `click` event. Working example :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.showBtn').forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert("test");
}))
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info showBtn" name="showBtn" 
id="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">View 
Employee</a> <br/>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info showBtn" name="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">View 
Employee</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info showBtn" name="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">View 
Employee</a>
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) only retrieves the first element. Use `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.showBtn').forEach(btn=>btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert("test");
}))
```

Alternatively, add a single listener to the parent of all buttons.

```html
<div id = "body">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info showBtn" name="showBtn" 
id="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">View 
Employee</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info showBtn" name="showBtn" 
id="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">View 
Employee</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info showBtn" name="showBtn" 
id="showBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">View 
Employee</a>
</div>
<script>
document.querySelector('#body').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.tagName === "A") //fire only if it's <a></a>
  alert("test");
})
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that too but TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function

Comment: @Bunny Sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As per MDN:

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

If you have multiple buttons sharing your 'showBtn' class then you can use querySelectorAll to instead return each one in a list. You can then iterate over that list to add your event listener to each one.

See the MDN page for [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

for select multi Dom element

The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

```
elements=[...document.querySelectorAll('.showBtn')];


elements.forEach((el)=>{

el.onclick=function(){

el.style.color='red';
console.log(el)
}
});
```